# Clustering strings in R (is it possible?)

Tags: r, csv, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with a column that is currently being treated as a factor with 1000+ levels. These are values for the column. I would like to clean up this data.
Some values are strings like "-18 + 5 = -13" and "5 - 18 = -13", I would like the clustering to group these differently than say "R3no4".

Is this possible in R? I looked at the natural language processing task view http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html but I need to be pushed in the right direction.

the dataset is from the [kdd 2010 cup](https://pslcdatashop.web.cmu.edu/KDDCup/downloads.jsp)
I would like to create meaningful new columns from this column to aid in creating a predictive model. for example it would be nice to know if the string contains a certain operation, or if it contains no operations and instead is describing the problem.

my data frame looks like this:

```
str(data1)
'data.frame':   809694 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Row                        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Anon.Student.Id            : Factor w/ 574 levels "02i5jCrfQK","02ZjVTxC34",..: 7 7     7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Problem.Hierarchy          : Factor w/ 138 levels "Unit CTA1_01, Section CTA1_01-1",..: 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 ...
 $ Problem.Name               : Factor w/ 1084 levels "1PTB02","1PTB03",..: 377 377 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 ...
 $ Problem.View               : int  1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ...
 $ Step.Name                  : Factor w/ 187539 levels "-(-0.24444444-y) = -0.93333333",..: 116742 177541 104443 64186 58776 58892 153246 153078 45114 163923 ...
```

I'm most interested in the Step.Name feature, since it contains the greatest number of unique factor values.

and some example values for step name:

```
[97170] (1+7)/4 = x                                                               
[97171] (1-sqrt(1^2-4*2*-6))/4 = x                                                
[97172] (1-sqrt(1^2-(-48)))/4 = x                                                 
[97173] (1-sqrt(1-(-48)))/4 = x                                                   
[97174] (1-sqrt(49))/4 = x                                                        
[97175] (1-7)/4 = x                                                               
[97176] x^2+15x+44 = 0                                                            
[97177] a-factor-node                                                             
[97178] b-factor-node                                                             
[97179] c-factor-node                                                             
[97180] num1-factor-node                                                          
[97181] num2-factor-node                                                          
[97182] den1-factor-node                                                          
[97183] (-15?sqrt((-15)^2-4*1*44))/2 = x                                          
[97184] (-15+sqrt((-15)^2-4*1*44))/2 = x                                          
[97185] (-15+sqrt((-15)^2-176))/2 = x                                             
[97186] (-15+sqrt(225-176))/2 = x                                                 
[97187] (-15+sqrt(49))/2 = x                                                      
[97188] (-15+7)/2 = x                                                             
[97189] (-15-sqrt((-15)^2-4*1*44))/2 = x                                          
[97190] (-15-sqrt((-15)^2-176))/2 = x                                             
[97191] (-15-sqrt(225-176))/2 = x                                                 
[97192] (-15-sqrt(49))/2 = x                                                      
[97193] (-15-7)/2 = x                                                             
[97194] 2x^2+x = 0                                                                
[97195] a-factor-node                                                             
[97196] b-factor-node                                                             
[97197] c-factor-node                                                             
[97198] num1-factor-node                                                          
[97199] num2-factor-node                                                          
[97200] den1-factor-node                                                          
[97201] (-1?sqrt((-1)^2-4*2*0))/4 = x                                             
[97202] (-1+sqrt((-1)^2-4*2*0))/4 = x                                             
[97203] (-1+sqrt((-1)^2-0))/4 = x                                                 
[97204] (-1+sqrt((-1)^2))/4 = x                                                   
[97205] (-1+1)/4 = x                                                              
[97206] (-1-sqrt((-1)^2-4*2*0))/4 = x                                             
[97207] (-1-sqrt((-1)^2-0))/4 = x                                                 
[97208] (-1-sqrt((-1)^2))/4 = x                                                   
[97209] (-1-1)/4 = x                                                              
[97210] x^2-6x = 0                                                                
[97211] a-factor-node                                                             
[97212] b-factor-node
```

Comment: Hi Harry, I'm not sure what you want to do. What do you mean by "clustering". Are you talking about sorting? You want to sort the rows of your dataset in a certain way? Could you please post a small part of your dataset and then show how, exactly, you would like that dataset to be ordered?

Comment: I think providing us with more of an example would help.  Something like this is what I have and this is the outcome I'd like.

Comment: If you need to be "pushed in the right direction" you need to explain in natural language what features distinguish "R3no4" from the other two expressions. Regular expressions could be used to distinguish alpha-containing character values. Where did these values come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clustering is just scoring each instance in a data array according to some metric, sorting the data array according to this calculated score, then slicing into some number of segments, assigning a label each one.

In other words, you can cluster any data for which you can formulate some meaningful function to calculate similarity of each data point w/r/t the others; this is usually referred to as a ***similarity metric***.

There are [a lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aStatistical_distance_measures) of these, but only a small subset of them are useful to evaluate strings. Of these, perhaps the most commonly used is ***Levenshtein Distance*** (aka *Edit Distance*).

This metric is expressed as an integer, and it increments one unit (+1) for each 'edit'--*inserting, deleting, or changing a letter*--required to transform one word into another. Summing those individual edits (one for each letter) gives you the Levenshtein Distance.

The R Package ***vwr*** includes an implementation:

```
> library(vwr)
> levenshtein.distance('cat', 'hat')
    hat 
    1 
> levenshtein.distance('cat', 'catwalk')
    catwalk 
    4 
> levenshtein.distance('catwalk', 'sidewalk')
    sidewalk 
    4

> # using a data set supplied with the vmr library 
> EW = english.words
> ew1 = sample(EW, 20)     # random select 20 words from EW
> # the second argument is a vector of words, returns a vector of distances
> dx = levenshtein.distance('cat', ew1)
> dx
furriers       graves      crooned    cursively       gabled   caparisons   drainpipes 
    8            5            6            8            5            8            9 
patricians     medially     beholder   chirpiness    fluttered     bobolink   lamentably 
    8            7            8            9            8            8            8 
depredations      alights    unearthed     thimbles    supersede   dissembler 
    10            6            7            8            9           10
```

While Levenshtein Distance *can be* used to cluster your data, whether it *should be* used for your data is a question i'll leave to you (i.e., the primary use case for L/D is clearly pure text data).

(Perhaps the next-most-common similarity metric that operates on strings is *Hamming Distance*. Hamming Distance (unlike Levenshtein) requires that the two strings be of *equal length*, hence it won't work for your data.)

Comment: Do you mean the package `vwr`? If not, where do you get `vmr` ?

Comment: also it should be noted that the Levenshtein distance is used in `utils::adist` and `base::agrep` so it might not be necessary to install a new package

Comment: yes, vwr, *not* vmr; i have corrected this typo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
> grepl("[[:alpha:]]", c("-18 + 5 = -13", "5 - 18 = -13","R3no4") )
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```