# Fast Levenshtein Distance (and Jaro Winkler) in R for numeric vectors

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, jaro-winkler

Is there a packagein R that contain Levenshtein Distance counting function that compute the distance for numeric vectors? All I have found are strings based. Also I am looking for a Jaro-Winkler package that do the same, but the Levenshtein distance is more essensial.

Comment: Have you tried `sos::???levenshtein`  ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There is no levenshtein function in sos package

Comment: @JackRyan how can I do that? I just found the simple strcmp()

Comment: POD, when text has a grey highlighter, it means it's a piece of code. In this case:  1) Load the package "sos" .  2) type exactly this: "???levenshtein"  3) take a gander at the search results.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I thought that you don't know the whole function. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Found this page:  [Clustering strings in R (is it possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468716/clustering-strings-in-r-is-it-possible)

which suggests using the `vwr` package.

Comment: I got the (vmr) from R CRAN archive. Is there a reason that is discontinued?